# OpenNETCF.Telephony detect incoming calls in WIndows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, telephony, windows-mobile-6, opennetcf

I develop an application related to managing calls under Windows Mobile 6. For the calls I use OpenNETCF.Telephony around TAPI.

I manage to detect and answer the first incoming call, but then, if I have another incoming call (when I already have an incoming call answered), this call is not detected. So, only the first incoming call is detected.

What should I do if I want to detect even the second incoming call?

Are there any settings I have to make to the cellular line, when I get it?

Does anyone know any issues about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I found the answer easy.

My settings for cellular line were

`tapi.CellularLine(MediaMode.InteractiveVoice, CallPrivilege.Owner)`

and I changed them to

```
tapi.CellularLine(MediaMode.InteractiveVoice, CallPrivilege.Monitor | CallPrivilege.Owner)
```